# How can i increase the amount of dataflow to lookup

Tags: ssis

In my package i have a source table having around 120000 records and a lookup transform with no cache mode and a destination table.I am passing data from source which is not matching with target into the same target table.When i execute the package i could see that,at a time only 9000 records only moving to lookup.once it insert into destination,other 9000 records move to lookup and go on.What is the reason of this only 9000 records?I tried by changing defaultbuffermaxrows and defaultbuffersize into different values,but 9000 record only moving at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in OLEDB destination we have a property `ROWS PER BATCH`. You can use that to change number of rows to transfer per batch.

Here, you see 9000 records movinf cause default maximum number of rows is 10,000.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141031.aspx)

> Define the default size of the buffer that the task uses, by setting
>   the DefaultBufferSize property, and define the maximum number of rows
>   in each buffer, by setting the DefaultBufferMaxRows property. The
>   default buffer size is 10 megabytes, with a maximum buffer size of 100
>   megabytes. The default maximum number of rows is 10,000.

**EDIT (Based on your comments):**

It's not working because you have set the `cache` options for `lookup` as `no cache`. To have it inserted/flow desired or custom rows (> default row) follow the below instructions.

- In your lookup setting make the `cache mode` to `Full cache`.
- In lookup use `OLEDB Connection manager`.
- in `OLEDB Destination` set the `ROWS PER BATCH` as mentioned above.
- In DataFlow properties set the `Default BufferMaxRow` to your desired rows.

Will work fine.

Comment: I have changed and tried the buffer size and number of rows,still it is 9000 rows at a time.If i remove the lookup it will load based on what ever i change.So,what is the reason?it is the setting of lookup?